# How to force user to pick date from p:calendar only by using mouse?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I need PrimeFaces calendar with `showOn="button"`. And I want to force user to pick date only by using mouse from popup. So only textbox input has to be readonly (or disabled).

I have tried with `readonlyInput`, but it doesn't work:

```
<p:calendar yearRange="2001:c+20" readonlyInput="true" id="test" showOn="button"
                    pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" value="#{mybean.value}" >
</p:calendar>
```

EDIT: Is is even possible to do?

Comment: `readOnlyInput` should work. That's what it's meant for according to the docs. What browser are you working in?

Comment: I would like to achieve that on any browser. I'm working on latest Chrome. I mean, is it really so hard to do? I need a control that is date-input, and allow user to pass date only by popup window (not manually by keyboard).

Answer (score 2):

Use the attribute **readonly** of the calendar: `readonly="true"`

Comment: It is sending null to backend...why is it so?